# How to Reverse Elements of A List And Its Sub-lists in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have the following piece of code:

```
(defun list-append (L1 L2)
  "Appending L1 by L2."
  (if (null L1)
      L2
      (cons (car L1) (list-append (cdr L1) L2))))

(defun list-reverse (L)
  "Create a new list containing the elements of L in reversed order."
  (if (null L)
      nil
      (list-append (list-reverse (cdr L)) 
                   (list (car L)))))
```

When I run the following:

```
(list-reverse '(a (b c) ((l k (t)) h i)))
```

The output I get is this:

```
(((L K (T)) H I) (B C) A)
```

However, I am trying to get it to print out the list as well as its sublists in reverse like so:

```
((I H ((T) K L)) (C B) A)
```

Any suggestions as to how I would modify the code to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422735/lisp-multi-level-recursive-reverse-function

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach to doing this which is not horrible.  In particular the accepted solution to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422735/lisp-multi-level-recursive-reverse-function) is algorithmically dreadful: any approach to reversing a list which says: 'to reverse a (perhaps very long list), first reverse the cdr of it then *append the car* to that should make your skin itch: this kind of approach is why 'lisp is slow'.  The two other answers are better, but both explicitly mutate state (which is fine, but perhaps not always pedagogically fine).

So here's an answer which: is functional (does not mutate state), and uses a non-horrible algorithm.

First of all, assume we have a function called `reverse-thing` which will do the appropriate reversing of a 'thing', where that means: if it's a list reverse it, and if it's not a list, don't.  Given that function we can work out an algorithm for reversing a list onto some other list:

To reverse a list onto another list

- if the list is empty return the list we're reversing onto
- otherwise reverse the rest of the list onto a list made by consing `reverse-thing` of the first of the list with the list we are reversing onto.

This is very simple to turn into a function:

```
(defun reverse-onto (list onto)
  (if (null list)
      onto
    (reverse-onto (rest list)
                  (cons (reverse-thing (first list))
                        onto))))
```

So this function needs a definition of `reverse-thing` so it can do its work.  Well how will this work?

To reverse a thing:

- if it is a list, then use `reverse-onto` to reverse it, onto `()`, the empty list;
- if it's not a list, return it as is.

And again, this is easy to turn into a function:

```
(defun reverse-thing (thing)
  (if (listp thing)
      (reverse-onto thing '())
    thing))
```

And we're done: `reverse-thing` is the function we wanted to write.

Note that these functions never mutate anything, and never look beyond the first cons of the list they're reversing in each step: there is no 'append this thing to (a copy of) this huge list' going on here.  Note also that `reverse-into` is tail-recursive, so in an implementation which optimizes tail calls (not required by the standard) the amount of stack will be proportional to the nesting depth not the list length.